# It is possible to send a link to an Android TV / Chromecast / Samsung TV / etc so that it opens in the native app

Tags: java, sdk, chromecast, android-tv, netflix

I have an Android app and I would like to be able to use it to send links from Netflix, Prime Video, HBO, etc to the TV (Android TV, Chromecast, Samsung TV or where possible) to play in the native TV app, similar to Android App Links, I have been watching the Cast SDK, but it seems that it only serves to send videos directly.

An example of what I would like to be able to do:

1. Press a Netflix link in the Android app (Movile device).
2. Show TVs on the same network and select one (Like Cast SDK)
3. TV opens link in native Netflix app

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does https://link2tv.com help?

There you can paste a URL and get a 9-digit Code that you can submit on the TV. Works for me with Youtube, Amazon Videos, Netflix links...

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you have the answer by now, namely Google TV, which will do exactly what is asked and more.

[image]

Just paste your link in this phone app area after clicking the field text area where you want it on the tv.

There are other applications like that which will do the same thing especially those for tv remote.